# What is the name of an anime about sisters working as maids?

Tags: he-is-my-master

I need help to identify an anime I saw 2 years ago that features a rich orphan. He meets two girls, one of whom is attacked and beaten up by an alligator.

The two girls are sisters, and begin working as maids for him.

Comment: ummmm some more info? drawing-style maybe? more character details?

Answer (score 7):

I think you may be looking for [He is My Master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_Is_My_Master) (aka *Kore ga Watashi no Goshujin-sama*) (it's a bit hard to tell because you haven't given a lot of information). It follows Yoshitaka, a 14-year-old orphan who inherited a large estate from his parents. He hires sisters Izumi and Mizuki as maids. They also bring their pet alligator Pochi, who often attacks Izumi. A third girl, Anna, appears later in the story as a maid.

The anime aired in 2005, while the manga ran from 2002 to 2009, so it fits your time frame.

[image]